# question on string in c++

Tags: c++

does     this work on string in c++?

```
string s="lomi";
cout<<s<<endl;
```

what is bad in this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string s=string("lomi");
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){


         s[i]= s[i]+3;
    }


    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;









     return 0;
}
```

?

Comment: What happened when you compiled and ran that code?

Comment: In fairness, what works on one compiler doesn't necessarily work on another, but I doubt the question was intended to ask if this invokes undefined behavior, which it obviously doesn't.

Comment: Of course no: there is no include and the symbols are undefined (you would need to qualify them with `std::`).

Comment: use #include <string> instead of #include <cstring>

Comment: You can test code like this at codepad.org without having to compile it on your machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

(after you have `#include`d the corresponding headers, and `using` the `std` namespace, etc.)

---

Edit: What's wrong with your code is you should

```
#include <string>
```

instead of

```
#include <cstring>
```

`cstring` is [C's `string.h` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h), which defines functions like `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc. that manipulates a C string, i.e. `char*`.

`string` defines C++'s `string` class which you're using.

Answer (score 4):

short answer: yes

long answer: `string s = "lomi"`works due to the `string(const char*)` constructor.

Comment: Try with std::cout << s << std::endl or with using namespace std.

Comment: string s = "lomi" invokes a constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: @Alexandre C: I would definitely not recommend the `using namespace` directive. It's dirty and prone to collisions. Better to promote either full qualification or `using std::cout;` syntax style.

Comment: @davit: What compiler did you use?  Similar issues could be caused by using gcc instead of g++.

Comment: i am using now  visual c++ 2010

Comment: @Matthieu Sutter might disagree with that (I'm a fan so I'd disagree as well) for ADL-related reasons (imagine the std::swap example used to demonstrate ADL-associated problems and forgetting to specify a using declaration on that). It does invite collisions across libraries but I think the ADL case (which can cause runtime behavioral problems) is much more problematic than something which would generally result in a build error.

Comment: Technically for completeness, one should also specify using std::operator<< and so on with using declarations.

Comment: @stinky: Nope, std::operator<< will be called because of argument dependent lookup

Comment: @Alexandre C: Yes, there is no need to explicitly state `using` with functions (except `std::swap`). However I still maintain than the `using namespace` directive is a bad idea. Qualifying does not cost much, really, and the `using std::xxx` for the most commonly used items is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me -- does it work for you?

Remember to do this first:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, cout in C++ knows how to deal with strings

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should compile and work, if you want to print "lomi\n", and you have included `<string>` and `<ostream>` and declared `using namespace std;`.